# Graphic effects are slow

Tags: 11.10, drivers, graphics, ati

İ'm using a HP Pavilion G6. Graphic card is HD6470M and switchable with HD4200. I have installed the proprietary driver in additional drivers. But graphic effects are very slow.

I also tried install up to date driver from ATI/AMD website but after restart system is not starting. Even if system starts don't work properly. So i removed the driver.

Now i am using the proprietary driver. When i open Catalyst CC i see HD4200 as active GPU. But also i see high performance GPU is active.

I take  a look on this site and found some answers but don't work.

(I am using 64bit Ubuntu 11.10)

I'm new in ubuntu and i will develop software on it.

Sorry for bad English. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I think that [this answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92419/hp-pavilion-g6-1209-temperature-higher-than-usual-and-fan-working-in-11-10) can be useful to you. It should also solve the overheating problem with your video card driver.

Comment: I can't use that solution. Because my pc's mainboard is different with that. I have an AMD powered pc not Intel. So i don't have an Intel o/b GPU. My o/b GPU is HD4200 and for use it i have to install same 6470M's driver.