# No video through HDMI

Tags: nvidia, video, hdmi

I just installed Ubuntu 14.04.2 with an Nvidia GeForce GT640 video card hooked up HDMI to my TV.  I don't have a monitor to plug into.  After install and reboot I don't have any video.  I get the first BIOS splash screen then I get a purple colored window, which I assume is the Ubuntu desktop color, then the screen goes blank and that's it.

Is there something I did wrong, or is there a fix to this before I reformat and reinstall again? This is a desktop PC, with onboard graphics and a GeForce GT640 installed. I went into BIOS and specified the Nvidia card as the primary boot option.

I booted into recovery mode and had it repair anything it needed to repair. When it was done, I got to the desktop, then a message popped up saying it needed to restart to apply new updates, when it rebooted again, no desktop again, TV says no signal.

Comment: possible duplicate of [nvidia card driver not detected: no settings & cannot use HDMI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/139565/nvidia-card-driver-not-detected-no-settings-cannot-use-hdmi)

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.  I tried `apt-get install nvidia-current` and it never worked, then I realized I had to type `sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`.

That worked and all is good now.