# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS ati / amd driver not able to install

Tags: unity, drivers, ati, proprietary

I'm a beginner who just set up a dual boot with Win7 home and
**Ubuntu 12.04LTS**. As seen in many tutorial videos and as Ubuntu suggested I tried to install the proprietary drivers.

my specs: *dell vostro 3550*
 - cpu - i5 2410M @ 2.30GHz x4
 - gpu - sandy bridge mobile (+ Radeon HD 6630M)
 - ram - 3,8Gb
 - Ubuntu 64bit 12.04LTS (win7 Home Prem. 64bit)

->  It detects a ATI/AMD driver and an additional driver update.

**my problem:**
after installing the first driver Unity is not working correctly it is probably Unity2D ...
can't install the prorietary driver-addition to get it working flawless
*the amd catalyst control center won't work since it doesn't detect a properly installed graphics driver*

so far I've tried to install

- solely the first proprietary driver however the catalyst control center wouldn't work
- the update for the proprietary driver but
  somehow failed and after a reboot it showed me none of both drivers is
  running (no green point).
- I've tried the driver from amd's website (
  http://support.amd.com/de/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx | http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx)

... after all I couldn't manage to get any driver working

**help please ...   it's much appreciated because at the moment the
graphics card seems to be running all the time consuming much energy**

update1:

> 2012-10-03 19:24:57,214 WARNING: /sys/module/fglrx_updates/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind fglrx_updates driver
>   2012-10-03 19:25:14,448 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
>   2012-10-03 19:25:14,448 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
>   2012-10-03 19:25:14,480 DEBUG: fglrx.enabled(fglrx_updates): target_alt None  current_alt /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf other target alt None other current alt /usr/lib/fglrx/alt_ld.so.conf
>   2012-10-03 19:25:14,480 DEBUG: fglrx_updates is not the alternative in use
>   getting this jockey.log once I try to install the additional driver!
>
> tried to install the additional driver because unity2D (the message confirmed my estimation) crashed due to some driver thing afaik
>
> commencing to lose confidence this post will help me and my problem will be fixed - :(

update2:

> another try to install the above mentioned drivers from AMD's website led the system to boot into low graphics mode.
>   I could remove it because the catch still included these commands to remove the drivers
>   http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to install the proprietary drivers for ati because of the overheating problem like you. At last I found the best solution for me was to turn off the ati and use my Intel integrated graphics card instead. If your laptop support switchable graphics, you may tries this:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

For more details, see [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103253/how-do-i-turn-off-the-radeon-gpu-ono-my-hp-pavilion-dm4).

Hope this can help you. :-)

Comment: thank you so much! I'm definitively work thru this post and try to switch it off -> that would help a lot