# VGA switcheroo doesn't work on 14.04 intel/ati acer 5820TG

Tags: ati, 14.04, hybrid-graphics, vgaswitcheroo

Before I updated from 13.10 to 14.04, vga switcheroo worked fine, using the free radeon-driver. Now vga switcheroo doesn't work anymore/doesn't take effect:

```
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0 1:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0 2:DIS-Audio: :Pwr:0000:01:00.1
```

after trying to turn off the unused discrete graphic:

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
cat /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
0:IGD:+:Pwr:0000:00:02.0 1:DIS: :DynPwr:0000:01:00.0 2:DIS-Audio: :Pwr:0000:01:00.1
```

Is there anyone with the same isue or was anyone able to use vga switcheroo on Ubuntu 14.04?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable ATI discrete graphic GPU at startup in Ubuntu 14.04 without BIOS?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/450410/how-can-i-disable-ati-discrete-graphic-gpu-at-startup-in-ubuntu-14-04-without-bi)