# Turn off useless video card ubuntu server

Tags: server, graphics, ati, radeon

I have a

VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Cedar [Radeon HD 5000/6000/7350/8350 Series] connected to my computer which is now a development server.

It gets HOT!

I basically don't want it there at all, but the computer won't start without it.

How do I either:

- Turn it off
- Reduce its power
- Boot up independently of it

The computer is a studio xps 9100 that has always had problems with the graphics card. It would be quite liberating to finally be free of the never-ending hot-enough-to-boil-water-graphics-card issue.

Answer (score 0):

you should install proprietary drivers from Radeon, thermal settings are highly customisable in Catalyst.

also what other GPU you have? if it`s NVidia then you can manually assign it to anything your XServer use via NVidia XServer settings.

also check this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450410/how-can-i-disable-ati-discrete-graphic-gpu-at-startup-in-ubuntu-14-04-without-bi), it should contain some info which can help you: