# Should I disable AMD graphic

Tags: amd-graphics

I have dual graphic in my laptop 
AMD radeon 7670M
And Intel HD 
After I installed Ubuntu 16.04
Fan speed is quite high and my laptop lags whenever I view videos on browser or open Facebook
Is it due to the AMD drivers no more supported in 16.04
Can I disable AMD and use only Intel

I have dual boot and I use Ubuntu for development stuff so is it possible to use dual graphics in Windows while using only Intel in Ubuntu ?

Is it good to turn off the AMD and will it decrease the noisy fan and the lags I face

Comment: IF still experiencing issues with this, see my answer to this question : http://askubuntu.com/questions/771562/16-04-power-off-discrete-graphics-ati-amd/872190#872190

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can deactivate the AMD graphics and just use only the intel graphics without problems.

In case you have not already installed it before - install the `gksu` package from the repositories.

Open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

Now execute this command :

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Add `radeon.modeset=0` to this line : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"

so that it reads : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash radeon.modeset=0"

Save the changes you made.

Then execute this command :

```
sudo update-grub
```

Reboot the system and from now on you are using the intel graphics ... and AMD is deactivated.

Comment: Will there be any problem . can I enable it again . can you please post how to enable it also for future reference

Comment: @Ezio : There will be no problem to re-enable the AMD graphics later - just do the same again, but this time remove  radeon.modeset=0 from the line, then update GRUB and reboot the operating system. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Will disabling from ubuntu will also disable it from Windows ?

Comment: @Ezio : No, of course not - Windows is a different operating system with completely different drivers. :)

Comment: @cl-netbox, I tried the same on my Dell Inspiron 15R 7520 with AMD Radeon HD 7730M. However, instead of Ubuntu, I'm using Debian 8, and the value for GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT was "quite". Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: @arthursfreire : quiet or quiet splash is not important (just a difference between debian and Ubuntu), important is to add the parameter radeon.modeset=0 ... it should work in debian as well, because this parameter is related to the kernel for booting the computer with the AMD graphics drivers disabled. :)