# How to disable Redeon Graphic Drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I am installing **Ubuntu**, I am facing problem with black screen also the i have face this problem with **Windows 10** after update drivers or update windows 10.

In windows 10 I disable **Redeon Graphic Drivers** and use **Intel Graphic Drivers 3000** which works good.

Now i am installing Ubuntu and facing the same problem.

Comment: I don't want that drivers cuz it's not working. I want default Intel drivers only.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I disable AMD graphic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771838/should-i-disable-amd-graphic)