# How to disable the discrete graphics on 16.04?

Tags: drivers, graphics, 16.04, radeon, amd-graphics

Before the update to 16.04 I used to use a proprietary driver from AMD only to disable the discrete graphics card. But now, on the newest version of Ubuntu this is not possible (the Catalyst driver cannot be installed for the version of Xorg in the newest release).

I've tried other ways, but with no success. This [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771562/16-04-power-off-discrete-graphics-ati-amd/775056#answer-775056) **gave no result**, though the output of the command looked as if the card had been disabled:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I've tried several other approaches, but each of them to no avail, it was either not working with the 16.04 kernel (`4.4.0-22-generic`) or something else.

Does anyone know, how can the discrete graphics card be disabled on the latest Ubuntu (16.04)?

Comment: Since you seem to have no use for it, why don't you physically disconnect it from your PC? It's not soldered out or anything.

Comment: @ipselute, I have a laptop, and for me it is not so pleasant task to get inside it. Once I did to clear dust from it and spent almost all day, as I remember, let alone that I'm not sure if it is possible on my laptop at all

Comment: If you have not installed any driver for your discrete graphic card i see no way for Ubuntu to use it. Just to make sure, install hardware detection tools like i-nex and see if Ubuntu recognize your card. If it does not, then Ubuntu can't use it. Install the latest driver for your other card.

Comment: @ipselute, sorry, I didn't get the previous comment. If I didn't install any driver for my discrete card, Ubuntu had to use an open source driver. Ubuntu recognizes the card, I think, because `lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'` lists `Kernel driver in use: radeon`. And I think that I don't need any drivers for my other card which is Intel's integrated one, it works fine, but the discrete graphics is too hot. I'm trying to disable it at all.

Comment: And I just checked the manual for my Dell Vostro 3350 and there is no way to remove the graphics card.

Comment: Sorry about that, man! Have you tried this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/450410/how-can-i-disable-ati-discrete-graphic-gpu-at-startup-in-ubuntu-14-04-without-bi. Some possible solution at page bottom.

Comment: @ipselute, thank you, the answer, suggested by you, has helped. I had to pass `radeon.runpm=0` to the kernel instead of `radeon.modeset=0`. Please, post the answer, I'll accept it, otherwise I'll remove the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for a change :

[How can I disable ATI discrete graphic GPU at startup in Ubuntu 14.04 without BIOS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/450410/how-can-i-disable-ati-discrete-graphic-gpu-at-startup-in-ubuntu-14-04-without-bi).

Some possible solution at page bottom. In particular, try to pass `radeon.runpm=0` to the kernel instead of `radeon.modeset=0` .