# Overheating on Ubuntu 16, dual graphic card Intel - ATI

Tags: 16.04, intel-graphics, radeon, overheating

I always had this trouble with overheating, but with my upgrade to 16.04 (from 14), it's even worse. The computer fan goes crazy, the temperature rises to 70° without doing anything, so I don't even dare to launch my statistical softwares.

So far I've tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/771562/16-04-power-off-discrete-graphics-ati-amd) on my HP Pavilion dv6. 
Without any improvement. Maybe my problem is not even coming from that.

Any help would be much appreciated, I'd rather avoid to go back to 14.04 and have to reinstall everything...

As requested :

```
$ lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
Mode(s) opératoire(s) des processeurs :32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) par cœur : 2
Cœur(s) par socket : 2
Socket(s):             1
Nœud(s) NUMA :       1
Identifiant constructeur :GenuineIntel
Famille de processeur :6
Modèle :             42
Model name:            Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2430M CPU @ 2.40GHz
Révision :           7
Vitesse du processeur en MHz :2868.093
CPU max MHz:           3000,0000
CPU min MHz:           800,0000
BogoMIPS:              4789.11
Virtualisation :      VT-x
Cache L1d :           32K
Cache L1i :           32K
Cache L2 :            256K
Cache L3 :            3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
Flags:                 fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
```

Comment: Let's start with something simple: have you checked if you have too much dust accumulation and remove the dust with compressed air?

Comment: Please install and run Psensor and report with component is getting so hot.

Comment: @edwinksl : yes I did

Comment: @AndroidDev : on Psensor I get all Temp1, Physical Id, Core 0 and Core 1 at 70° at least. CPU usage is at 5% and my HDD at 40°.

Comment: Please edit your post to include the output of `lscpu`.

Comment: @AndroidDev will do asap. At work without my laptop today. Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Guys, I'm so sorry, but my supervisor made me understand we need to work on my laptop tomorrow, so I had no other choice to do a fresh install of the 14.04 release.

I'm so sorry for the waste of time, once again, thanks for having helped me !

Answer (score 1):

/*sorry for this I wanted to comment but for some weird reason this page does not let me do that.*/

I'm not a guide but I read several times problems like that, and the best thing to do is to use a kernel release that is equal to your laptop release date.
I experienced the same heat problem, and compiling old kernel was the solution, maybe you should try that.
In my case deleting ubuntu from my laptop was the best thing to do, maybe ubuntu is not setting things, maybe missing parameters or whatever, I don't know why but windows works like a charm, and just for the problem of heat I returned to windows, now w10 have bash(beta) so I dont see any difference of changing for the simple things i do.

Heat is really a problem because it determines how much time your laptop will live, I've tried mint, fedora and even arch but my problem persisted(also I wanted to try many distros because why not) but finally I decided to go to windows because my work and my life needs that, so Im sure is a kernel problem maybe torvalds doesnt like my laptop =/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment Renato. I didn't know this question of kernel could impact computer performance.
This is my second computer using Ubuntu, and I experience once again overheating issue. I'm not even playing anygame: browsing, OO and some statistical softwares. I first attributed the pb to my hardware (DELL), but since I get it also with HP... 
I really appreciate how easy it is to set up a system with Ubuntu, but if there is everytime a problem as major as overheating, maybe it isn't worth it. Such a pity because I really appreciate it, and do not really want to go back to W.

Comment: Another solution might be to buy a laptop already under Ubuntu? I guess in these cases the machine is running flawless...