# Hp pavilion G6 laptop getting hot in palm resting area ,after dual booting to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

I searched for the issue I have. some mentioned heating might be with two graphics cards running even when there is no workload(browsing chrome) 
. My notebook is  *Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Thames [Radeon HD 7500M/7600M Series] (rev ff)*
As I am using 18.04 AMD no support for proprietary drivers, using open source drivers. 
[software & updates screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFIA9.png)

After running this cmd

> lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'

```
Kernel driver in use: i915
Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Is there any way I can use only intel graphic or disable Radeon. In bios of HP, there is no *switchable graphics mode*.

Finally, I am not going to game on Ubuntu, for the coding purpose only. I can't downgrade to ubuntu 14.04 where I have fglrx support.
I even used TLP but still getting hot in palm resting area, the fan is barely running.

1) from this user answer  [Stackoverflow answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/775056/309944) I disabled amd graphics card,kernal in use only i915.

2) TLP started in battery mode

In idle usage,running Psensor only for 20min apprx hitting 77C max
[image: Psensors screenshot]